# CopyLocal = True for GAC assemblies

Tags: .net

How does CopyLocal = True work for assemblies registered in GAC? What if two GAC-assemblies with the same name are referenced to a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing two assemblies with the same name *already* has lots of problems; some with workarounds (extern alias), some not. You're best avoiding this by a long distance.

Re choosing to copy-local; that is handy if **you** have it in the GAC, but the target machine might not; for example, you can deploy MVC-3 using copy-local without installing anything on the servers, but on a dev machine they are most likely in the GAC.

Comment: A PIA that you don't want to deploy would be another example.  It is not that common to actually need them.  Made irrelevant with .NET 4's support for embedding interop types anyway.